# gcc-5: internal compiler error: Bus error (program as)

Tags: 14.04, python, compiling, gcc

I'm trying to install Python 2.7.11 on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS vServer (hosted at strato), because it's a requirement for letsencrypt.

I'm using [this tutorial](https://www.ralphlepore.net/installing-python-279-on-ubuntu-1404-lts/), basically just replacing 2.7.9 with 2.7.11.

Now when I'm trying to run

```
./configure
```

I get the error

```
C Compiler cannot create executables
```

I have no idea what is causing this

My `config.log` file:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by python configure 2.7, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = h2577734.stratoserver.net
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 3.13.0-042stab111.12
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Thu Sep 17 11:38:20 MSK 2015

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2816: checking build system type
configure:2830: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:2850: checking host system type
configure:2863: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:2974: checking for --enable-universalsdk
configure:3015: result: no
configure:3025: checking for --with-universal-archs
configure:3042: result: 32-bit
configure:3199: checking MACHDEP
configure:3391: result: linux2
configure:3400: checking EXTRAPLATDIR
configure:3415: result: 
configure:3436: checking for --without-gcc
configure:3480: result: no
configure:3574: checking for gcc
configure:3590: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:3601: result: gcc
configure:3830: checking for C compiler version
configure:3839: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.5
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3850: $? = 0
configure:3839: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.5 (Ubuntu 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 
configure:3850: $? = 0
configure:3839: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3850: $? = 4
configure:3839: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3850: $? = 4
configure:3870: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3892: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
gcc: internal compiler error: Bus error (program as)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.
configure:3896: $? = 4
configure:3934: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define _GNU_SOURCE 1
| #define _NETBSD_SOURCE 1
| #define __BSD_VISIBLE 1
| #define _BSD_TYPES 1
| #define _DARWIN_C_SOURCE 1
| #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
| #define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1
| #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3939: error: in `/home/username/Downloads/Python-2.7.11':
configure:3941: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR=''
ARCH_RUN_32BIT=''
ARFLAGS=''
BASECFLAGS=''
BASECPPFLAGS=''
BLDLIBRARY=''
BLDSHARED=''
BUILDEXEEXT=''
CC='gcc'
CCSHARED=''
CFLAGS=''
CFLAGSFORSHARED=''
CONFIGURE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=''
CONFIG_ARGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX=''
DEFS=''
DLINCLDIR=''
DLLLIBRARY=''
DYNLOADFILE=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENSUREPIP=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPORT_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='#'
EXTRAMACHDEPPATH=''
EXTRAPLATDIR=''
FRAMEWORKALTINSTALLFIRST=''
FRAMEWORKALTINSTALLLAST=''
FRAMEWORKINSTALLAPPSPREFIX=''
FRAMEWORKINSTALLFIRST=''
FRAMEWORKINSTALLLAST=''
FRAMEWORKUNIXTOOLSPREFIX='/usr/local'
GNULD=''
GREP=''
HAS_HG=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_3_ARG=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_5_ARG=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_6_ARG=''
HGBRANCH=''
HGTAG=''
HGVERSION=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
INSTSONAME=''
LDCXXSHARED=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDLAST=''
LDLIBRARY=''
LDLIBRARYDIR=''
LDSHARED=''
LIBC=''
LIBFFI_INCLUDEDIR=''
LIBM=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBRARY=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL_CRUFT=''
LINKCC=''
LINKFORSHARED=''
LIPO_32BIT_FLAGS=''
LLVM_PROF_ERR=''
LLVM_PROF_FILE=''
LLVM_PROF_FOUND=''
LLVM_PROF_MERGER=''
LN=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MACHDEP='linux2'
MACHDEP_OBJS=''
MAINCC=''
MKDIR_P=''
MULTIARCH=''
OBJEXT=''
OPT=''
OTHER_LIBTOOL_OPT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='http://bugs.python.org/'
PACKAGE_NAME='python'
PACKAGE_STRING='python 2.7'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='python'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='2.7'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PGO_PROF_GEN_FLAG=''
PGO_PROF_USE_FLAG=''
PKG_CONFIG=''
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=''
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=''
PLATDIR='plat-linux2'
PYTHONFRAMEWORK=''
PYTHONFRAMEWORKDIR='no-framework'
PYTHONFRAMEWORKIDENTIFIER='org.python.python'
PYTHONFRAMEWORKINSTALLDIR=''
PYTHONFRAMEWORKPREFIX=''
PYTHON_FOR_BUILD='./$(BUILDPYTHON) -E'
RANLIB=''
RUNSHARED=''
SGI_ABI=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
SHLIBS=''
SIGNAL_OBJS=''
SO=''
SOVERSION='1.0'
SRCDIRS=''
SVNVERSION=''
TCLTK_INCLUDES=''
TCLTK_LIBS=''
THREADHEADERS=''
THREADOBJ=''
TRUE=''
UNICODE_OBJS=''
UNIVERSALSDK=''
UNIVERSAL_ARCH_FLAGS=''
USE_SIGNAL_MODULE=''
USE_THREAD_MODULE=''
VERSION='2.7'
_PYTHON_HOST_PLATFORM=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='unknown'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='unknown'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#define _NETBSD_SOURCE 1
#define __BSD_VISIBLE 1
#define _BSD_TYPES 1
#define _DARWIN_C_SOURCE 1
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L

configure: exit 77
```

I'm seeing fatal errors after `gcc -V` and `gcc -qversion`, but I've read somewhere that they are part of the normal building process.

So I wrote a `helloworld.c` file and tried to compile that, but the compiler returned:

```
gcc internal compiler error: Bus error (program as)
```

The same error is also in my `config.log` from trying to compile python.

I can barely find any information about that error when googling, how can I fix this?

EDIT:

Further investigation (see comments):

```
$ which as
/usr/bin/as

$ as --version
bus error

$ gcc -print-prog-name=as
as

$ apt-cache policy binutils
binutils:
  Installiert:           2.24-5ubuntu14.1
  Installationskandidat: 2.24-5ubuntu14.1
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 2.24-5ubuntu14.1 0
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.24-5ubuntu3 0
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages

$ file /usr/bin/as
/usr/bin/as: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=de7c02da59248e5021aefd9d4959fcc749abeec6, stripped
```

`ldd /usr/bin/as` returns nothing.

Comment: I'm confused. The default gcc for 14.04 is 4.8.4; your title mentions `gcc-5` but the error messages from the configure script say `gcc version 6.1.1 20160511 (Ubuntu 6.1.1-3ubuntu11~14.04.1)`. How (and why) did you install gcc-6.1?

Comment: Oh sorry I posted the wrong config.log, first I tried it with 4.8.4 which didn't work. Then I saw

    gcc --version >&5

in the config.log and thought, that this means that I might need gcc version 5 and above.

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/python2.html States as well that:

    This package is known to build properly using the gcc-6 compiler.

So I thought why not install gcc 6, when it failed again I tried gcc 5 because I thought maybe 6 is too new and still has a few bugs.

I installed both this way: https://gist.github.com/beci/2a2091f282042ed20cda

Comment: `gcc --version >&5` is nothing to do with version greater than 5: it means "run the command `gcc --version` and send its output to file descriptor number 5". I'd suggest running `sudo update-alternatives --config gcc` again and setting the value back to the default one. Then start over.

Comment: Just use this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes-python2.7

Comment: I reverted to using gcc 4.8 but the problem still remains (I updated the config.log in the Post).

The PPA works fine, but since I need gcc for letsencrypt as well it doesn't really help far.

Comment: OK please add the outputs of the following commands: `which as`, `as --version` and `gcc -print-prog-name=as`

Comment: which as returns "/usr/bin/as"; as --version returns "bus error"; gcc -print-prog-name=as returns "as". Could this be a problem with my RAM?

Comment: I don't see any reason to suspect a RAM problem. What does `apt-cache policy binutils` say?

Comment: apt-cache policy binutils prints:

binutils:
  Installiert:           2.24-5ubuntu14.1
  Installationskandidat: 2.24-5ubuntu14.1
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 2.24-5ubuntu14.1 0
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.24-5ubuntu3 0
        500 ftp://ftp.stratoserver.net/pub/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages

I've read that bus error might indicate broken RAM.

Comment: What do `file /usr/bin/as` and `ldd /usr/bin/as` say? BTW please [edit] your question with this information instead of posing it via comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40754/discussion-between-steeldriver-and-jojo-ilkischmilki).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see from your diagnostic output, `gcc` uses the external program `as` (which is `/usr/bin/as`) - the GNU assembler - and it is this that is failing.

Somehow, it appears that the `as` binary executable has been corrupted on your system, to the point where even `/usr/bin/as --version` causes a bus error. (Although apparently it is intact enough for the `file` program to correctly identify it). Since `as` is provided by the `binutils` package, the solution turns out to be reinstalling that package i.e.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall binutils
```